# Removing an item from a list of String and StringBuilder during for loop doesn't give the same output

Tags: java

Can anyone explain to me the cause of these two different console outputs :

```
public class Test {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         List<StringBuilder> dryFruits = new ArrayList<>();
         dryFruits.add(new StringBuilder("Walnut"));
         dryFruits.add(new StringBuilder("Apricot"));
         dryFruits.add(new StringBuilder("Almond"));
         dryFruits.add(new StringBuilder("Date"));

         for(int i = 0; i < dryFruits.size(); i++) 
         {
             if(i == 0) {
                 dryFruits.remove(new StringBuilder("Almond"));
             }
          }
         System.out.println(dryFruits);
     }
}
```

> Output => [Walnut, Apricot, Almond, Date]

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> dryFruits = new ArrayList<>();
        dryFruits.add(new String("Walnut"));
        dryFruits.add(new String("Apricot"));
        dryFruits.add(new String("Almond"));
        dryFruits.add(new String("Date"));

        for(int i = 0; i < dryFruits.size(); i++)
        {
            if(i == 0) {
                dryFruits.remove(new String("Almond"));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(dryFruits);
    }
}
```

> Output => [Walnut, Apricot, Date]

Answer (score 2):

`StringBuilder` doesn't override `Object`'s `equals`. Therefore `dryFruits.remove(new StringBuilder("Almond"))` doesn't remove the previously added `new StringBuilder("Almond")` instance (which is not the same instance).

`String` does override `equals`, and therefore `dryFruits.remove(new String("Almond"))` removes the `String` instance that contains the same value.